Why I didn't win the Hook Turn achievement with this game?
While playing mini-metro, I did this game:

All lines are connected to this one middle square. Why I didn't win the Hook Turn achievement with this game?
Here is the achievement Hook Turn description:


My guess would be that at some point they were briefly disconnected.
https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=591641788 is a Steam guide for getting this achievement.

I guess so. just unlocked it.
